# Whatsapp Business API production setup not working

Tags: docker-compose, whatsapp

I am trying to configure or setup the production environment of whatsapp business api as mentioned in the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/prod-single-instance
I have done everything mentioned in this my dockers are also running on `port:9090` as can be seen in the image [image]
still I can't access it. Whenever I try to call `https://localhost:9090` the error with `"This site can’t be reached"` occurs. Whatsapp business api does not have good documentation or tutorials till now. So this site is the only last way for me.

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Naah.. mate, it's really confusing.

Comment: Everything i have set up when i try to access it from browser or Postman its giving me error as "This site can’t be reached" .Everything is up and running. Its strange issue,

Comment: did you select the environment as WABiz Developer?

Comment: Yes and pasted the localURl in to variables

Comment: ok, write me an email at farukhcs15@gmail.com so we can talk about this and come up with the solution. We can then paste it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195173/discussion-between-farrukh-ahmed-khan-and-rahul).

Comment: Is the response of 'healthcheck' same as the documentation mentions at [WhatsApp Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/prod-single-instance) point number 9? It should say 'unregistered'. 

If it does, then you need to complete the registration step and start sending messages (more specifically, start ahead with point number 10 from the link mentioned above)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem which could be your case, I saw the docker containers OK but nothing was working. After a day searching I saw where it happened, my problem was I installed mysql MANUALLY (not docker container) in the same instance where docker is running and in db.env I just used 127.0.0.1, this was passed literally to docker container, then looking at a the wait_on_mysql.sh script, the whastapp docker containers were waiting util the mysql ip has conectivity to actually do something and was printing "MySQL is not up yet - sleeping" each second, of course they wouldn't find any conectivity.

Since my instalation is for development, and I am already using such database to other stuff, my solution was to use the 172.17.0.1(docker gateway of the containers) IP instead, then add two sets of network iptables rules to the host to redirect from the docker containers IP to the IP binded by mysql when using such port (3306, the default in my case). After that everything works well. I think there are better solutions, but I didn't want to go far on it, you should evaluate you case if apply.

check the command:

`docker-compose logs > debug_output.txt`

That gives you insight about whats happening, hope it can helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup is already complete. You just need to start with the registration process and start sending messages. The containers are up and running but calling https://localhost:9090 won't send you any response as this is not any specified API endpoint expected to be used.

Since you're using prod single instance, the documentation can be found here which seems pretty straight forward. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/prod-single-instance

You seem to have completed till the 7 steps. The next step can be to perform a health check to make sure it is healthy. The API endpoint for that would be `https://localhost:9090/v1/health` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/health

Comment: @navjod : I can not check health too. I have the same issue as farhaan as asked. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Has your db also been setup?
I cannot see it in the docker screenshot.

Also - you have to accept the certificate, as it does not have a public CA issues certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. However when you will have 50 points you will be able to post in comment this kind of post. As this question is a bit old you may have not any feedback soon. I invite you to take a moment to read this guide [answer]